# Parsing scutil output with perl

Tags: regex, json, macos, perl, parsing

I would like to retrieve information from Mac OSX's `scutil` command with a perl script.

The output generated by that tool is somewhat similar to JSON, but so far I failed to find anything that is capable of parsing that.

Example:

```
scutil
> open
> show State:/Network/Service/0F70B221-EEF7-4ACC-96D8-ECBA3A15F132/IPv4
<dictionary> {
  ARPResolvedHardwareAddress : 00:1b:c0:4a:82:f9
  ARPResolvedIPAddress : 10.10.0.254
  AdditionalRoutes : <array> {
    0 : <dictionary> {
      DestinationAddress : 10.10.0.146
      SubnetMask : 255.255.255.255
    }
    1 : <dictionary> {
      DestinationAddress : 169.254.0.0
      SubnetMask : 255.255.0.0
    }
  }
  Addresses : <array> {
    0 : 10.10.0.146
  }
  ConfirmedInterfaceName : en0
  InterfaceName : en0
  NetworkSignature : IPv4.Router=10.10.0.254;IPv4.RouterHardwareAddress=00:1b:c0:4a:82:f9
  Router : 10.10.0.254
  SubnetMasks : <array> {
    0 : 255.255.255.0
  }
}
```

I already managed to retrieve particular elements via regexps, but as I need to make several different lookups, I'm looking for a smarter, more generic approach.

Now, before I reinvent the wheel by coding yet-another-perl-parser, I hope that somebody recognizes this format and can give some advise how to parse this in - let's say - a nested perl hash map.

Any comments welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Perl, you can use [Marpa::R2](https://metacpan.org/release/Marpa-R2), a Perl interface to [Marpa, a general BNF parser](http://savage.net.au/Marpa.html).

Here is a quick example:

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Deepcopy = 1;

use Marpa::R2;

my $g = Marpa::R2::Scanless::G->new( { source => \(<<'END_OF_SOURCE'),
    :default ::= action => [ name, value]
    lexeme default = action => [ name, value] latm => 1

    scutil ::= 'scutil' '> open' '> show' path '<dictionary>' '{' pairs '}'
    path ~ [\w/:\-]+

    pairs ::= pair+
    pair ::= name ':' value
    name ~ [\w]+
    value ::= ip | mac | interface | signature | array | dict

    ip ~ octet '.' octet '.' octet '.' octet
    octet ~ [\d]+
    mac ~ [a-z0-9][a-z0-9]':'[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]':'[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]':'[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]':'[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]':'[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]
    interface ~ [\w]+

    signature ::= signature_item+ separator => [;]
    signature_item ::= signature_item_name '=' signature_item_value
    signature_item_name ~ [\w\.]+
    signature_item_value ::= ip | mac

    dict  ::= '<dictionary>' '{' pairs '}'
    array ::= '<array>' '{' items  '}'
    items ::= item+
    item ::= index ':' value
    index ~ [\d]+

    :discard ~ whitespace
    whitespace ~ [\s]+
END_OF_SOURCE
} );

my $input = <<EOI;
scutil
> open
> show State:/Network/Service/0F70B221-EEF7-4ACC-96D8-ECBA3A15F132/IPv4
<dictionary> {
  ARPResolvedHardwareAddress : 00:1b:c0:4a:82:f9
  ARPResolvedIPAddress : 10.10.0.254
  AdditionalRoutes : <array> {
    0 : <dictionary> {
      DestinationAddress : 10.10.0.146
      SubnetMask : 255.255.255.255
    }
    1 : <dictionary> {
      DestinationAddress : 169.254.0.0
      SubnetMask : 255.255.0.0
    }
  }
  Addresses : <array> {
    0 : 10.10.0.146
  }
  ConfirmedInterfaceName : en0
  InterfaceName : en0
  NetworkSignature : IPv4.Router=10.10.0.254;IPv4.RouterHardwareAddress=00:1b:c0:4a:82:f9
  Router : 10.10.0.254
  SubnetMasks : <array> {
    0 : 255.255.255.0
  }
}
EOI

say Dumper $g->parse( \$input, { trace_terminals => 0 } );
```

Output:

```
\[
    'scutil',
    'scutil',
    '> open',
    '> show',
    [
      'path',
      'State:/Network/Service/0F70B221-EEF7-4ACC-96D8-ECBA3A15F132/IPv4'
    ],
    '<dictionary>',
    '{',
    [
      'pairs',
      [
        'pair',
        [
          'name',
          'ARPResolvedHardwareAddress'
        ],
        ':',
        [
          'value',
          [
            'mac',
            '00:1b:c0:4a:82:f9'
          ]
        ]
      ],
      [
        'pair',
        [
          'name',
          'ARPResolvedIPAddress'
        ],
        ':',
        [
          'value',
          [
            'ip',
            '10.10.0.254'
          ]
        ]
      ],
      [
        'pair',
        [
          'name',
          'AdditionalRoutes'
        ],
        ':',
        [
          'value',
          [
            'array',
            '<array>',
            '{',
            [
              'items',
              [
                'item',
                [
                  'index',
                  '0'
                ],
                ':',
                [
                  'value',
                  [
                    'dict',
                    '<dictionary>',
                    '{',
                    [
                      'pairs',
                      [
                        'pair',
                        [
                          'name',
                          'DestinationAddress'
                        ],
                        ':',
                        [
                          'value',
                          [
                            'ip',
                            '10.10.0.146'
                          ]
                        ]
                      ],
                      [
                        'pair',
                        [
                          'name',
                          'SubnetMask'
                        ],
                        ':',
                        [
                          'value',
                          [
                            'ip',
                            '255.255.255.255'
                          ]
                        ]
                      ]
                    ],
                    '}'
                  ]
                ]
              ],
              [
                'item',
                [
                  'index',
                  '1'
                ],
                ':',
                [
                  'value',
                  [
                    'dict',
                    '<dictionary>',
                    '{',
                    [
                      'pairs',
                      [
                        'pair',
                        [
                          'name',
                          'DestinationAddress'
                        ],
                        ':',
                        [
                          'value',
                          [
                            'ip',
                            '169.254.0.0'
                          ]
                        ]
                      ],
                      [
                        'pair',
                        [
                          'name',
                          'SubnetMask'
                        ],
                        ':',
                        [
                          'value',
                          [
                            'ip',
                            '255.255.0.0'
                          ]
                        ]
                      ]
                    ],
                    '}'
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ],
            '}'
          ]
        ]
      ],
      [
        'pair',
        [
          'name',
          'Addresses'
        ],
        ':',
        [
          'value',
          [
            'array',
            '<array>',
            '{',
            [
              'items',
              [
                'item',
                [
                  'index',
                  '0'
                ],
                ':',
                [
                  'value',
                  [
                    'ip',
                    '10.10.0.146'
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ],
            '}'
          ]
        ]
      ],
      [
        'pair',
        [
          'name',
          'ConfirmedInterfaceName'
        ],
        ':',
        [
          'value',
          [
            'interface',
            'en0'
          ]
        ]
      ],
      [
        'pair',
        [
          'name',
          'InterfaceName'
        ],
        ':',
        [
          'value',
          [
            'interface',
            'en0'
          ]
        ]
      ],
      [
        'pair',
        [
          'name',
          'NetworkSignature'
        ],
        ':',
        [
          'value',
          [
            'signature',
            [
              'signature_item',
              [
                'signature_item_name',
                'IPv4.Router'
              ],
              '=',
              [
                'signature_item_value',
                [
                  'ip',
                  '10.10.0.254'
                ]
              ]
            ],
            [
              'signature_item',
              [
                'signature_item_name',
                'IPv4.RouterHardwareAddress'
              ],
              '=',
              [
                'signature_item_value',
                [
                  'mac',
                  '00:1b:c0:4a:82:f9'
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ],
      [
        'pair',
        [
          'name',
          'Router'
        ],
        ':',
        [
          'value',
          [
            'ip',
            '10.10.0.254'
          ]
        ]
      ],
      [
        'pair',
        [
          'name',
          'SubnetMasks'
        ],
        ':',
        [
          'value',
          [
            'array',
            '<array>',
            '{',
            [
              'items',
              [
                'item',
                [
                  'index',
                  '0'
                ],
                ':',
                [
                  'value',
                  [
                    'ip',
                    '255.255.255.0'
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ],
            '}'
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ],
    '}'
  ]
```

Comment: Very cool! FYI, Generally it's better to include code and output directly in your answers instead of in gists so users don't have to visit an external site and to avoid the possibility of link-rot. I've taken the liberty of editing the gists into your answer, I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

The solution with [Marpa::R2](https://metacpan.org/release/Marpa-R2) is actually a nice generic approach.
However, I'm not so happy with the generated hash map, which is probably the toll one has to pay for the generic parser.

I've come up with the following code to get a more *straight* hash map:

```
use Data::Dumper;

open(my $pipe, '-|', "scutil <<- end_scutil 2> /dev/null
open
show State:/Network/Service/21AD96AA-AD28-4D5C-93C1-F343FD07DA60/IPv4
close
end_scutil") or die $!;

sub doParse {
  my ($type)=@_;
  my $map;
  my @arr;

  while(<$pipe>) {
    chomp;
    if ($type eq "dictionary") {
      if (m/^<dictionary> \{/) {
        $map=doParse("dictionary");
      } elsif (m/\s*([^:]+) : <(.*)> \{/) {
        $map->{$1}=doParse($2);
      } elsif (m/\s*([^:]+) : ([^\}]+)$/) {
        $map->{$1}=$2;
      } elsif (m/\}$/) {
        return $map;
      } else {
        print STDERR "$type parse error on $_";
      }
    } elsif ($type eq "array") {
      if (m/\s*(\d+) : <(.*)> \{/) {
        $arr[$1]=doParse($2);
      } elsif (m/\s*(\d+) : ([^\}]+)$/) {
        $arr[$1]=$2;
      } elsif (m/\}$/) {
        return \@arr;
      } else {
        print STDERR "$type parse error on $_";
      }
    }
  }
  return $map;
}

print Dumper(doParse("dictionary"));

1;
__END__
```

With this input from `scutil`

```
<dictionary> {
  ARPResolvedHardwareAddress : 00:1e:8c:72:27:d2
  ARPResolvedIPAddress : 192.168.1.10
  AdditionalRoutes : <array> {
    0 : <dictionary> {
      DestinationAddress : 192.168.1.232
      SubnetMask : 255.255.255.255
    }
    1 : <dictionary> {
      DestinationAddress : 169.254.0.0
      SubnetMask : 255.255.0.0
    }
  }
  Addresses : <array> {
    0 : 192.168.1.232
  }
  ConfirmedInterfaceName : en0
  InterfaceName : en0
  NetworkSignature : IPv4.Router=192.168.1.10;IPv4.RouterHardwareAddress=00:1e:8c:72:27:d2
  Router : 192.168.1.10
  SubnetMasks : <array> {
    0 : 255.255.255.0
  }
}
```

it produces this hashmap:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'InterfaceName' => 'en0',
          'Addresses' => [
                           '192.168.1.232'
                         ],
          'ARPResolvedHardwareAddress' => '00:1e:8c:72:27:d2',
          'NetworkSignature' => 'IPv4.Router=192.168.1.10;IPv4.RouterHardwareAddress=00:1e:8c:72:27:d2',
          'ARPResolvedIPAddress' => '192.168.1.10',
          'AdditionalRoutes' => [
                                  {
                                    'SubnetMask' => '255.255.255.255',
                                    'DestinationAddress' => '192.168.1.232'
                                  },
                                  {
                                    'DestinationAddress' => '169.254.0.0',
                                    'SubnetMask' => '255.255.0.0'
                                  }
                                ],
          'Router' => '192.168.1.10',
          'SubnetMasks' => [
                             '255.255.255.0'
                           ],
          'ConfirmedInterfaceName' => 'en0'
        };
```